# HIbernate @OneToOne mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a PatientVisit.java that has a one to one mapping with the PatientVisitObject.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "P_Visit")
public class PatientVisit extends Bean {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "PATIENT_VISIT_SEQ")
  private Long patientVisitSeq;
  @Column(name = "PATIENT_FIRST_NM")
  private String firstName;
  @Column(name = "PATIENT_LAST_NM")
  private String lastName;
  @Column(name = "PATIENT_MIDDLE_NM")
  private String middleName;
  @OneToOne
  private PatientVisitObject pvo;
}
```

The PatientVisitObject.java has a composite key.  I need to map key.patientVisitSeq to my patientVisitSeq in the PatientVisit.java.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Patient_V_O")
public class PatientVisitObject extends Bean {
  @Id
  private PatientVisitObjectKey key;
  @Column(name = "FIELD")
  private String field;
}
```

Here is the key:

```
@Embeddable
public class PatientVisitObjectKey implements Serializable {
  @Column(name = "PATIENT_VISIT_SEQ")
  private Long patientVisitSeq;
  @Column(name = "PATIENT_VISIT_OBJECT_SEQ")
  private Long patientVisitObjectSeq;
}
```

I have tried using the @JoinTable annotation and cannot get it right.  Could someone please give me some direction.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use bidirectional mapping with `PatientVisit` being the inverse side of relationship:

```
public class PatientVisit extends Bean {
    ...
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "pv")
    private PatientVisitObject pvo;
    ...
}

public class PatientVisitObject extends Bean {
    @EmbeddedId
    private PatientVisitObjectKey key;

    @OneToOne 
    @MapsId("patientVisitSeq")
    private PatientVisit pv;

    ...
}
```

**See also:**

- [`@MapsId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapsId.html)